# Google Script - How to add formula to cells when row data updated?

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, formula, multiple-columns, typeform

I have a google sheet linked to a Typeform.  Data comes into the sheet when the type form is completed in the next blank row populating columns A-I.

When the data comes through I would like this to trigger some fairly standard formulas to be entered into columns K-N (4 columns).

How would I have these formulas added to specified columns when the sheet is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a script with a Form submit trigger. This function will be called each time a form response is submitted. In that function you will execute the logic to populate your cells with the formulas you need.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1